# How to use the 'replace' feature for custom AngularJS directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does `replace=true` or `replace=false` not have any impact in the code below?

Why isn't the "some existing content" being displayed when replace=false?

Or putting it more humbly, can you kindly explain what is the `replace=true/false` feature in directives and how to use it?

**Example**

JS/Angular:

```
<script>
    angular.module('scopes', [])
          .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.title = "hello";

          })
          .directive('myDir', function() {
            return {
              restrict: 'E',
              replace: true,
              template: '<div>{{title}}</div>'
            };
      });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <my-dir><h3>some existing content</h3></my-dir>
</div>
```

See it in Plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4ywZGwfsKHLAoGL38vvW?p=preview

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### `replace:true` is Deprecated

From the Docs:

> `replace` ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)
>
> specify what the template should replace. Defaults to `false`.
>
> - `true` - the template will replace the directive's element.
> - `false` - the template will replace the contents of the directive's element.

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

From GitHub:

> [Caitp--](https://github.com/caitp) It's deprecated because there are known, very silly problems with `replace: true`, a number of which can't really be fixed in a reasonable fashion. If you're careful and avoid these problems, then more power to you, but for the benefit of new users, it's easier to just tell them "this will give you a headache, don't do it".

-- [AngularJS Issue #7636](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7636)

---

## Update

> Note: `replace: true` is deprecated and not recommended to use, mainly due to the issues listed here. It has been completely removed in the new Angular.

### Issues with replace: true

- [Attribute values are not merged](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#attribute-values-are-not-merged)
- [Directives are not deduplicated before compilation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directives-are-not-deduplicated-before-compilation)
- [`transclude: element` in the replace template root can have unexpected effects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-transclude-element-in-the-replace-template-root-can-have-unexpected-effects)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Issues with `replace:true`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#issues-with-replace-true-)

Comment: I keep reading that this is supposed to be unofficially supported in Angular 2, but I can't figure out how to activate it. Can someone tell me what the syntax is?

Comment: @devios I need such thing for my mdl components but currently using `remove-host` workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280475/remove-the-host-html-element-selectors-created-by-angular-component if you find out about activating `replace: true` in A2 let us know.

Answer (score 191):

When you have `replace: true` you get the following piece of DOM:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="ng-binding">hello</div>
</div>
```

whereas, with `replace: false` you get this:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" class="ng-scope">
    <my-dir>
        <div class="ng-binding">hello</div>
    </my-dir>
</div>
```

So the `replace` property in directives refer to whether the element to which the directive is being applied (`<my-dir>` in that case) should remain (`replace: false`) and the directive's template should be **appended** as its child,

OR

the element to which the directive is being applied should be **replaced** (`replace: true`) by the directive's template.

In both cases the element's (to which the directive is being applied) children will be lost. If you wanted to perserve the element's original content/children you would have to translude it. The following directive would do it:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div>{{title}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };
});
```

In that case if in the directive's template you have an element (or elements) with attribute `ng-transclude`, its **content** will be replaced by the element's (to which the directive is being applied) original content.

See example of translusion http://plnkr.co/edit/2DJQydBjgwj9vExLn3Ik?p=preview

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296284/how-to-understand-the-transclude-of-directive-defination) to read more about translusion.

Comment: This is a wonderfully simple explanation. And thanks a bunch for clarifying the transclusion too.

Comment: More importantly, why isn't it explained at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and why doesn't this answer link to a definitive answer on the topic?

Comment: @Trindaz `replace` has been deprecated since AngularJS v1.3 ([link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.11/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-)).