# Angular attribute directive that wraps its element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

like the title says, I'm attempting to make an attribute directive that wraps its parent and allows me to toggle between editing and showing the actual model value..

In short:

```
<input ng-model="model" allow-edit="editing" />
```

Would end up looking like:

```
<div>
    <div ng-hide="editing">{{model}}</div>
    <input ng-show="editing" ng-model="model"></input>
</div>
```

If everything went right.

However, I keep on getting something more along the lines of:

```
<input ng-model="model">
    <!-- html from allow-edit directive's template --!>
</input>
```

I've used input as an example here, but I'd like to be able to wrap arbitrary content (select, etc) as well...

Has anyone been able to make a directive that wraps other content on the same element?  Is there a better way to do this that I'm not considering?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is `replace:true` but maintain `"=ngModel"`

```
replace:true,
scope:{
  mymodel:"=ngModel",
  editing:"=allowEdit"
}
```

Heres a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uMPQaaeaIMb0QqqENhCZ?p=preview)

Comment: It should be noted that any other attributes you apply to the input element will be lost -- they are migrated to the wrapper element. So this addresses the specific example in the question, it has serious limitations.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answers your question:
In directive options:

1. set `replace: true`
2. set `transclude: "element"`
3. use `ng-transclude` where ever you want to put the original element within the wrapper template.

### [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/vyhJcH9OVMyP9gEB55yl?p=preview)

## example:

### js:

```
var app = angular.module("test", []);

app.directive("myCustomInput", function($rootScope){
  return{
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,
    transclude: "element",
    template: "<div class='input-wrap'>"+
    "<div ng-transclude></div>"+
    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></i>"+
    "</div>"
    
  }
});
```

### HTML:

```
<input my-custom-input type="text" />
```

Comment: While this solution nicely wraps the original input element without modifying it, there is no toggling going on here, which is what the question was about.

Comment: While it wraps the HTML as asked, for some reasons attributes like `ng-model` are broken with this method and do not work anymore on the wrapped input.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `replace : true` should enable you to replace the original content. Take a look at this StackOverflow answer:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true)

If you had a bit more of your directive, I could have a go at getting it to work, but hopefully you can use the plnkr of the other answer to work it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I wouldn't like to actually replace the original content though... Instead, I'd like to insert the original content into my directive template.