# AngularJS : Wrapping an element into a custom template with an angular attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, transclusion

## Situation:

I have an attribute directive that wraps it's element into a template. Here it is:

```
app.directive("myCustomInput", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,
    scope:{},
    transclude: "element",
    template: "<div class='input-wrap'>"+
    "<div ng-transclude></div>"+
    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></i>"+
    "</div>"
  }
});
```

And I use it like:

```
<input my-custom-input ng-model="data.input" type="text" />
```

## Problem:

`ng-model` doesn't work
**Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/llhGyyLL4CGqqQDxLnar?p=preview)**

Comment: Funny thing i just noticed is this was an answer you provided for [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295882/angular-attribute-directive-that-wraps-its-element/27648516#27648516)? :)

Comment: :)) exactly! I was actually using what I said in that answer, until I encountered my own problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have encountered a possibly bug. It is a priority and directive processing order issue. Set your directive higher priority than the ng-model. When using 1.2 v, ng-model has the default priority of `0` and with 1.3 version `ng-model` has a priority `1`. So let your directive have a higher priority than the ng-model so that the directive and transclusion happens before `ng-model` processes the input before your directive renders.

```
.directive("myCustomInput", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,
    scope:{},
    priority: 1, //Here set the priority
    transclude: "element",
    template: "<div class='input-wrap'>"+
    "<div ng-transclude></div>"+
    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></i>"+
    "</div>"
  }
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vu9b2BaSBcWxEP1C358W?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the "bug" more?