# Angular ng-animate 1.3.* Causes to unexpected behavior to ng-class inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate, ng-class, isolate-scope

I'm in the middle of the transition from version 1.2.* to 1.3.* , and I came across a very strange and **critical** bug.

In my application I have a very simple `directive` contain a `template` with `ng-class` (with condition to scope property) for some reason it's not working with 1.3.* version, and it's work fine with 1.2.* version.

Have a look on this  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQ3n1CyeIvDBb7vAsRBH?p=preview) to illustrates the problem.

This `Plunker` code is with angular 1.2.* version, and as you can see it's work fine.

Try to change the angular version (index.html)

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-animate.js"></script>-->
```

**Refresh** the page, and then you can see the **bug:**
Angular doesn't refresh the ng-class according to the 'active' property changing.

I tried to understand what can causes to this bug, and after a lot of tries I found that `'ngAnimate'` module causes to this problem. try to delete the `'ngAnimate'` dependency (script.js):

```
  //var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

And then you can see that everything is fine, so `'ngAnimate'` version 1.3.* causes to this problem.

So it's **AngularJS bug**, am I right?

If not, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was experiencing an issue with ng-class since upgrading where the class either didn't update, or it kept both the old and new value on the scope variable being updated.  I had ng-animate module referenced but wasn't actually using it.  Since removing that reference, I havent seen the issue so far.

Comment: did you check this? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#animation-nganimate-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have any specific reason to use the `replace` option in the directive? If not, you can just remove it and it works fine. Link to working plunker with Angular 1.3.9:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jLIS9uJ1PHC64q6nEmtB?p=preview

[V1.3.9 docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-) tell that `replace` is deprecated and very rarely needed for directives to work, and apparently in your case it also managed to cause some trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc `replace` will be deprecated in version 2. As you are using Angular 1.3.9, that should be fine.

To fix this issue either you can remove `replace` from directive or still if you want to use `replace` then wrap directive template content which has `ng-transclude` in a div like below

`<div><div ng-click='click()' ng-class='{\"{{defaultColorClass}}\" : !active, \"{{activeColorClass}}\": active, \"mousePointer\" :  !active}' class='k-content-button-inner-style {{effectClass}} {{externalClass}}'  ng-transclude></div></div>`

For more info refer - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude , [Explain replace=true in Angular Directives (Deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true).

Answer (score 1):

[@bensiu:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367878/bensiu) Removing the unused* variable `{{effectClass}}` in the `template` will make it work for 1.4.4 in the `plunker` example linked to the question.

Modified plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9IHuysfqUQw15xKnM14?p=preview)

*Edit: Probably I should say "using a variable not in scope" rather than "unused variable".