# Directive Element Not displaying directive name in mark up

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I want to hide the Directive name markup from my html

Right now I am doing this

```
<option-found-address-display></option-found-address-display>
```

But when this renders/compiles I just want to show the contents of the directive. Not the actual `<option-found-address-display>`and then my content within.

I am pretty sure I saw a way how to hide this but can't remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.directive('optionFoundAddressDisplay', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>your content</div>',
    replace:true
  }
});
```

will hide the directive name markup from the html.

`Replace:true` does the trick.

[For more about replace:true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true)

Comment: restrict should be `'E'`