# “replace: true” with ng-if in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created new custom angularjs directive (d-emails). The template of this directive contains "ng-if" directive. And in this directive we can see "replace: true". The main reason of this - just because I want to check user role inside of the directive and then if user doesn't have an appropriate role to remove whole element from html. I don't want to leave element with class="col-sm-6" inside html. But when I wrote this code I realize that in this case I can't use isolated scope. Ng-if removed my isolated scope and added new scope inherited from the parent scope. Any suggestions how to manage this situation? 
I saw the similar questions like this [Issue with isolated scope and "replace: true" in angular directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246102/issue-with-isolated-scope-and-replace-true-in-angular-directive) but I couldn't find any appropriate solutions.

```
function dEmails() {
    var directive = {
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            entityId: "=",
            entityType: "="
        },
        controllerAs: "vm",
        templateUrl: "/directives/d-emails.tmpl.html",
        restrict: "E",
        controller: dEmailsController,
        replace: true
    };
    return directive;
}

dEmailsController.$inject = ['roleService'];

function dEmailsController(roleService) {
    var vm = this;
    init();
    var roleId = 4;
    vm.isApproved = false;

    function init() {
        roleService.hasRole(roleId).then(function(isApproved) {
            vm.isApproved = isApproved;
            if (isApproved) {
                emailResource.get({ entityId: vm.entityId, entityType: vm.entityType }).$promise.then(function(response) {
                    vm.list = response.Result;                        
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Where d-emails.tmpl.html looks like this:

```
<div class="email-item" ng-if="vm.isApproved">
    <div>Content of my super directive</div>
</div>
```

And code where I use this directive:

```
<d-emails class="col-sm-6" entity-id="vm.entityId" entity-type="vm.entityType.event">
</d-emails>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ng-if just remove element in directive when vm.isApproved is false.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it is useful to look at the problem at the other side:-)

Comment: Just one more comment to this solution. Our template in this case will render before. Of course we can add something like "ng-show" to the root of the template but I don't think this will be the best solution.