# get access to $scope in ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

What is the better approach to get access to scope created by ng-if in my directive (without $parent.params.text):

```
<span ng-if="params" uib-tooltip="{{params.text}}"></span>

.directive('myDirective', functions(){
   return {
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      replace: true,
      $scope: {
         data: '='
      },
      controller: function(){
          if (data) { //some logic
             $scope.params.text = 'text'
          }
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: i found that it's not working because i use replace: true

Comment: replace: true parameter is deprecated, this is [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35519198/5727598)

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that I don't have to use `$parent` if my variable is nested inside an object.

For example:

**controller**
`$scope.params = { ... }`

**view** `ng-if="params"`

Won't work, but:

**controller**

```
$scope.something_here = {};
$scope.something_here.params = { ... }
```

**view** `ng-if="something_here.params"`

***would*** work. I believe Angular preserves the scope if the key you're trying to access is part of an object. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the controllerAs syntax.

add

```
controllerAs: "vm",
bindToController: true
```

as properties in your directive definition and replace $scope with vm.
Then refer to vm.params.text inside the ng-if