# Angular 2nd directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 directives in one page. The first one works fine, but the second one not working.

This is my Code:

HTML

```
<body class="login" ng-app="Login">
<div ng-controller="HttpLoginController">
<wrongdetails></wrongdetails>
<loading></loading>
<input type="submit" ng-click="LoginUser()" value="Login" />
</div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("Login", [])
app.controller("HttpLoginController", function($scope,$http){
$scope.LoginUser = function(){
$scope.loading = true;
var data = [];
var config = {}
$http.post('Mylink', data, config)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.loading = false;})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {$scope.wrongdetails = true; });
};      
});
//Directives
app.directive('loading', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //replace:true,
        template: '<div id="loading"> <div class="progress-line"></div><br/> </div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
    }
})
app.directive('wrongdetails', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="alert alert-danger display-hide"><button class="close" data-close="alert"></button><span> Error. </span></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('wrongdetails', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
    }
})
```

But The second Directive never show.
What I am doing wrong?

Sorry for my mistake. I forget to copy paste the directives.
I think now is ok

Comment: You should provide the code for the both directives (if you have any). Otherwise your question is not really complete...

Comment: Sorry, I forget to copy paste the directives.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line in your second directive:-

```
replace:true ,
```

The reason with the explanation is already available. Refer this link [Explain replace=true in Angular Directives (Deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true)

Comment: I remove the line but still the second directive not showing