# ng-disabled on both directive element (replace: true) and in directive template combine improperly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It appears using ng-disabled on an element directive with `replace: true` and on the root element of the directive's template results in angular incorrectly trying to combine the two ng-disabled conditions.

html:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <my-submit-button ng-disabled="condition1"></my-submit-button>
</body>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.condition1 = true;
});

app.directive('mySubmitButton', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.condition2 = false;
    },
    template: '<button type="button" ng-disabled="condition2">My Button</button>'
  };
});
```

Results in rendered html:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="condition1 condition2">My Button</button>
```

Notice `condition1 condition2` doesn't have an `&&` in between.

Here is a [jsBin example](https://jsbin.com/xuseverose/edit?html,js,console,output) of the problem.

Is this an angular bug or am I missing something?

And if it is angular's fault, is there a way I can handle it more gracefully? Adding `scope: {ngDisabled: '='}` to the directive doesn't seem to stop angular from automatically combining (incorrectly) condition1 and condition2.

Also, if it is an angular bug, where do I report it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain replace=true in Angular Directives (Deprecated)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/explain-replace-true-in-angular-directives-deprecated). See [AngularJS Issue #7636](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7636).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `replace: true` is deprecated so known bugs won't be fixed. Or so I gather from [Why is replace deprecated in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs)