# How to avoid rendering directive element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to hide my directive html element?
I mean if I have this directive:

app.js

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("myDirective", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<div><p>Some text...</p></div>"
    }
);
```

Only render the content of the template.

```
<div>
    <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

Not the directives element:

```
<my-directive>
    <div>
        <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
</my-directive>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes just put the `replace: true` in the directive. it will remove the element

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("myDirective", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<div><p>Some text...</p></div>",
            replace: true
    }
);
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){


}).directive("myDirective", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<div><p>Some text...</p></div>",
            replace : true
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <my-directive> 
</my-directive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that **replace: true** is marked as deprecated (I use it myself nonetheless from time to time)

See: [Explain replace=true in Angular Directives (Deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/explain-replace-true-in-angular-directives-deprecated)