# Angularjs Interpolation using double curly braces not working under ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, interpolation, angular-ng-if

**UPDATE1:** developed the plunker sample that will reproduce the problem. See below.

I have a strange problem in my project, where it appears in one place only. Finally, I was able to reproduce the problem using plunker sample:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JJbq54?p=preview

In the above sample, see the section "With ng-if" and "Without ng-if", enter something in the input text, and see how the double curly braces not working under `ng-if`, but `ng-bind` works fine. Also, if you remove `check-if-required` from the template `sites-and-improvements.html` also the problem is solved.

---

## More details below:

I have the the following HTML5 code block:

```
    <div ng-if="isFullCUSPAP" id="sites_and_imrpovements_comments">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="inputs-group">
                <label>WIND TURBINE:</label>
                <div class="input-binary">
                    <label>
                       <input type="radio" id="wind_turbine" 
                              name="wind_turbine"
                              ng-model="$parent.wind_turbine" 
                              value="Yes" force-model-update />
                       Yes
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-binary">
                    <label>
                      <input type="radio" id="wind_turbine"
                             name="wind_turbine" 
                             ng-model="$parent.wind_turbine" 
                             value="No" force-model-update />
                      No
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span ng-bind="wind_turbine"></span>
                <span>wind_turbine = {{wind_turbine}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I know that `ng-if` will create a new child scope. See above code, scope variable `wind_trubine`. Only in this HTML5 file, the curly braces `{{}}` is not working. However, if I use `ng-bind` it works fine. In other HTML5 files, I have no problem what so ever. This HTML5 is implemented using directive as follows:

```
app.directive('sitesAndImprovements', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        templateUrl: '<path-to-file>/site-and-improvments.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //Business Logic for Sites and Improvements
        }
    } 
})
```

And, simply, I put it in the parent as follows:

```
<sites-and-improvements></sites-and-improvements>
```

The only difference I could see, is that this implementation has two levels of nested `ng-if`, which would look like the following:

```
<div ng-if="some_expression">
    ...
    ...
    <sites-and-improvements></sites-and-improvements>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

Based on comments, I used `controller As` notation and defined `MainController` accordingly. See snapshots below. It seems there is a problem if `ng-if` is nested with two levels. The scope variable is completely confused. I don't get the same results using `ng-bind` and double curly braces.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

If you examine the above snapshots, even though I used `controller As` notation, you will see that `ng-bind` gives different results when compared with interpolation using `{{}}`.

I even changed the default value of `wind_turbine` to be set as follows in the link function:

```
scope.MainController.wind_turbine = 'Yes';
```

I noticed that on page load, everything looks fine, but when I change the value of the input element `wind_trubine` using the mouse, all related reference are updated correctly except the one that uses `{{}}`.

Maybe this is because there are two nested levels of `ng-if`?

Appreciate your feedback.

Tarek

Comment: you're relying on `wind_turbine` being in your scope. `ng-if` creates a new inner scope, so what you should do is have a `controllerAs="vm"` or something like that in the `ng-controller` line (probably this syntax, but I might be wrong), and then use `vm.wind_turbine` instead of directly using `wind_turbine`

Comment: this looks like a case where the golden rule for angularjs applies:  **always use a dot in angular bindings**.  (in other words, bind to object properties, not primitives).

Comment: It is not wise to depend on `$parent` in `ng-model` getting to the correct scope. If there are two levels of scope created by two levels of `ng-if` directives, the value will be placed on a scope that is unavailable to the binding.

Comment: @GioraGuttsait: I followed you recommendation, and still same problem. See updated description above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

Comment: @georgeawg - I updated the description with more details. This is most likely a bug or some other issue. See the plunker sample I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `replace: true` from the `sites-and-improvements` directive:

```
app.directive('sitesAndImprovements', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        ̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶:̶t̶r̶u̶e̶,̶
        templateUrl: 'site-and-improvments.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
          //debugger;
        }
    } 
})
```

It is fighting the `check-if-required` directive:

```
app.directive('checkIfRequired', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
  return {
    priority: 2000,
    terminal: true,
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      el.removeAttr('check-if-required');

      $timeout(function(){
        //debugger;
        $(':input', el).each(function(key, child) {
          if (child && child.id === 'test_me') {
                angular.element(child).attr('ng-required', 'true');
                }
          if (child && child.id === 'testInput1') {
            //debugger;
                //angular.element(child).attr('ng-required', 'true');
                }
        });
            $compile(el, null, 2000)(scope);
      })
    }
  };
}])
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/S4z5lrdXMNiq0SGEiJGt?p=preview).

---

### [`replace:true` is Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35519198/5535245)

From the Docs:

> `replace` ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)
>
> specify what the template should replace. Defaults to `false`.
>
> - `true` - the template will replace the directive's element.
> - `false` - the template will replace the contents of the directive's element.

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - `replace` deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-)

From GitHub:

> [Caitp--](https://github.com/caitp) It's deprecated because there are known, very silly problems with `replace: true`, a number of which can't really be fixed in a reasonable fashion. If you're careful and avoid these problems, then more power to you, but for the benefit of new users, it's easier to just tell them "this will give you a headache, don't do it".

-- [AngularJS Issue #7636](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7636)

For more information, see [Explain replace=true in Angular Directives (Deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35519198/5535245)

Comment: Wow! thank you... just wondering now how this change will affect my project.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution posted by AngularJS team here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16140#issuecomment-319332063

Basically, they recommend to convert the `link()` function to use `compile()` function instead. Here is the update code:

```
app.directive('checkIfRequired', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
  return {
    priority: 2000,
    terminal: true,
    compile: function (el, attrs) {
      el.removeAttr('check-if-required');
      var children = $(':input', el);
      children.each(function(key, child) {
        if (child && child.id === 'test_me') {
            angular.element(child).attr('ng-required', 'true');
                }
      });
            var compiled = $compile(el, null, 2000);
            return function( scope ) {
                compiled( scope );
            };
    }
  };
}]).directive('sitesAndImprovements', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        templateUrl: 'site-and-improvments.html'
    } 
});
```

The main problem I have with this solution is that I am using the `scope` parameter which is passed to the `link()` function. For example, in the `.each()` loop above, I need to get the value of the element ID which is based on interpolation using `{{<angular expre>}}`.

So I tried to use `pre-link` and `post-link` within the `compile` function where the `scope` is available. I noticed that the section with `ng-if` is removed when execution is in `pre-link` and then it is added shortly after that. So I had to use `$watch` to monitor changes to the children to run the needed process when required. I developed this plunker sample:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lsJvhr?p=preview

Even after all such effort, the issue is not resolved. So the bottom line for similar cases, is that if you need to use the scope then you have to remove `replace: true`.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Tarek