# Add ng-class attribute to root element of angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I hav a directive that looks roughly like this, with an `ng-class` in the template:

```
module.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: `<div ng-class="{'foo-expanded': expanded, 'foo': !expanded}"><div>`
        //...
    }
}]);
```

My problem is, my classes from the `ng-class` are applied to the `div`, which ends up being nested inside of the directive element after the directive is compiled: `<my-directive><div>...</div></my-directive>`.

Is there any way to apply the classes to the root `<my-directive>` element instead? I know I can dynamically add the class using javascript in the link function or controller instead of the `ng-class`, but I am looking for a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the `link` function which gives you access to the created element ( directive )

```
module.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: `<div ng-class="{'foo-expanded': expanded, 'foo': !expanded}"><div>`
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {        
           element[0].classList.add('test')
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I would like to avoid adding the classes with javascript from the link function or controller. The problem is, that I would have to introduce a lot more complexity to get the same functionality as the `ng-class`. For example, I would need the method that toggles the `expanded` flag to to add and remove classes each time the flag changes (or something similar to that). However, your solution is likely to be the path I take if I can't figure out anything else, in which case I will select your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows two different ways

- Manipulate the classes from the controller
- Use `replace: true` (deprecated)

---

## Manipulate the classes from the controller

If you don't want to use `replace: true`, you can manipulate the directive's root classes from the controller by injecting `$element`.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: `
          <div ng-class="{'foo-expanded': expanded, 'foo': !expanded}">
             MY DIRECTIVE
          <div>
        `,
        controller: function($element) {
            $element.addClass("foo test test2");
            $element.toggleClass("foo-expanded");
            $element.removeClass("test2");
        }
    }
});
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/iKUH2rycP6f5g1Z01XVu?p=preview)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS element API Reference](https://plnkr.co/edit/iKUH2rycP6f5g1Z01XVu?p=preview)

---

## Use `replace: true` (deprecated)

Another approach is to use `replace: true`:

```
module.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: `<div ng-class="{'foo-expanded': expanded, 'foo': !expanded}"><div>`
        //...
    }
}]);
```

Keep in mind that the `replace` property is deprecated in AngularJS and has been removed in the new Angular (v2+).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - replace](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-)
- [How to use the 'replace' feature for custom AngularJS directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/how-to-use-the-replace-feature-for-custom-angularjs-directives/35519198#35519198)
- [Why is `replace` property deprecated in AngularJS directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-property-deprecated-in-angularjs-directives)
- [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Issues with `replace:true`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#issues-with-replace-true-).