# Use of $compile , transclude , Controller and link in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Recently I am going through concept of Custom Directives. When I was looking into deep of concepts I found few terminologies like

$compile -> Which traverse through DOM and find its directives
$tansclude -> Which is used to load template to another template. Its value is either true or false.
Controller -> Which is used to bind the DOM elements to $scope. This works before compilation
Link -> Which is used to link or bind data. This is done after DOM compilation.

How these are related to each other. What happens when we set transclude to false or true. When to use controller or link. How compiler is relates these functions. Is there is compulsory on using transclude. What is pre-link and post-link.

Comment: This is much too broad. Read the official documentation on directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: I have studied these concept from above links only but i am not getting clear picture of it

Comment: Compile vs Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164138/what-is-the-difference-between-compile-and-link-function-in-angularjs
Transclude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296284/understanding-the-transclude-option-of-directive-definition
Compile vs Link vs controller : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post
Explanations already exists, just use google :)