# Angular js : Unable to create directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create directive but my directive function is not getting called.

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="que in questions.Cars">
                             <question-dir>print from direcetive</question-dir>
</div>
```

ConytrolDirective.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("autoQuote")
        .directive('questionDir',["questionDir"] );

    function questionDir()
    {
        return {
            template : "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
        };
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code.

1. You should have function name instead of `"questionDir"`
   `.directive('questionDir',[questionDir] );`
2. Use [**kebab case**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?KebabCase)(`-` separated words) while using directive name

   ```
   `<question-dir>print from direcetive</question-dir>`
   ```
3. Additionally you need to refer `<script src="controlDirectives.js"></script>` on your index.html page.

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/i87a0DmynealFzLntCMi?p=preview)

Comment: thank you for the response. I updated code still no change.

Comment: Did you checked my plunkr?

Comment: How to pass que  to each directive?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see many mistakes in your code but it would have helped many to stop assuming only if you had posted your code sample link too.

But one primary change you have to make is : Change your directive definition function invoking from

```
.directive('questionDir', ["questionDir"])
```

to

```
.directive('questionDir', questionDir)
```

[See this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suman_jsfiddle/ehgpzqeq/) which has just added `questions.Cars` into `$rootScope` to make answer look more relevant to your query.

**To preserve content of your directive element :**

What i see in your question is : **Element** `<question-dir>` has child content / inner text `print from direcetive` in it and it gets overridden by **Directive Element** `<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>` completely.

That's the default nature of Angular : **Element**'s (to which the directive is being applied) children will be lost to **Directive Element**. If you wanted to perserve the element's original content/children you would have to translude it.

Use `transclude : true` in Directive Definition Object and add `<div ng-transclude></div>` where you want directive Content / text `print from direcetive` to be included.

Code snippet :

```
function questionDir() {
  return {
    transclude : true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div><h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
  };
}
```

[Check this one for transclude changes.](https://jsfiddle.net/suman_jsfiddle/ehgpzqeq/2/)

Check these 2 links for more information on **Transclude** :

- [Understanding the transclude option of directive definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296284/understanding-the-transclude-option-of-directive-definition)
- [Understanding transclude with replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true)

Answer (score 0):

You had a few things wrong in you code:

- In your IIFE closure you need to pass in `angular`
- You need to normalize the directive name to kabab case in your html element name: `'
- You need to include the reference to the directory factory in your directive registration: `.directive('questionDir', questionDir);`
- Missing module dependencies array: `.module("autoQuote", [])` -- you should only have this defined once with the dependancies, `[]` so ignore this if you already have it elsewhere in your code.
- Missing `restrict` in the Directive Definition Object: `restrict: 'E',`

If you click on `Run code snippet` you will see this directive now works.

```js
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("autoQuote", [])
        .directive('questionDir', questionDir);

    function questionDir()
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<h1>Made by a directive!</h1>"
        };
    }

}(angular));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="autoQuote">
  
    <question-dir>print from direcetive</question-dir>

</div>
```

Finally, if you are using AngularJS 1.5 or greater you should consider using the [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) syntax for this.

Comment: Its `IIFE` not `IIFY` and it isn't compulsory to pass `angular` parameter there. Its good to have practice..